# Add javascript to only post layout in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to conditionally add javascript to only post which is located inside (_layout) folder in jekyll. The conditions needs to be added inside default.html located inside (_layout) folder.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your directory structure? Which posts do you want it added to? Which don't you want it added to? Give us a specific example of directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

As your question I quite vague, I give you two tricks :

#### Adding something to all posts

```
{% if page.collection == "posts" %}do something{% endif %}
```

#### Adding something to any page/post using "post" layout (

```
{% if page.layout == "post" %}do something{% endif %}
```